# How to remove the last characters of each line in a file?

Tags: python

Say I have a file with these contents:

username1:password1:dd/mm/yy
username2:password2:dd/mm/yy
username3:password3:dd/mm/yy

How can I remove the last (9) characters from each line to leave only the username and password using Python?

Comment: Example:  Use slice method for example a = input("user name") then print(a[:-9) # -9 is slice element from backward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file with open("fileName.ext") method and then iterate each line. on each line you can perform the slicing function `[:]`

```
eachLineData = 'username1:password1:dd/mm/yy'
expectedResult = eachLineData[:-9]
print(expectedResult)
```

> Full Code Example:

```
# Using readlines()
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

for line in Lines:
    expectedResult = line[:-9]
    print(expectedResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file up using [`open("file.txt", "r")`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp), read it into a string, loop over each individual line using [`.splitlines()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_splitlines.asp), then remove the last 9 characters using the index `string[:-9]`.

```
>>> string = "username3:password3:dd/mm/yy"
>>> string[:-9]
'username3:password3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. The same `filename` is used when writing the result, so the original file will be overwritten (just use another `filename` for this if that's not what you want).

```py
# Read lines into list
filename = 'your_file_name'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Remove last n characters.
# Each line has an additional '\n' at the end,
# so we have to remove that one as well,
# then tack it back on.
n = 9
lines = [line[:-(n+1)] + '\n' for line in lines]

# Write modified lines back out
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

One could get by with only opening the file once, but I think it's nice to have a separate reading (`'r'`) and writing (`'w'`) stage.

Answer (score 1):

Most safe..

- Your input file (file.txt)

```
username1:password1:dd/mm/yy
username2:password2:dd/mm/yy
username3:password3:dd/mm/yy
```

The magic code

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as f:
    lines=[line[0:line.rindex(":")]+"\n" for line in f.readlines()]
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(lines)
```

The Output

```
username1:password1
username2:password2
username3:password3
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friends: A regular expression is a sequence of characters that looks for a specific search pattern. This code should work. Changing the 9 will change the amount of characters removed.

```
import re
line="username1:password1:dd/mm/yy"
print re.sub('.{0,9}\Z', '', line)
```

This concept extends to reading in a file just add a for loop